# How to change the connection limit of a HttpWebRequest/Response during program execution

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Is there a way to change the the number of connections allowed for a HttpWebResponse/Request during execution? I understand how to initially set this value on program start however changing the defaultConnectionLimit of the Service point manager class doesn't work once the program is executing.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: If you have a limited number of urls you request - you can modify service points of all of them. But otherwise it's quite problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over some more material online I was able to come up with a solution that works for me. In order to change the connection limit during execution you cannot use

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = number
```

This is partially because once the connection first goes through trying to use the previous line to change it will work as the connection with a limit to your host has already been established with a default limit, but after this point will not work as it'll only change new connections that need a new default limit.

You can however use

```
ServicePoint tmp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(hostUri);
tmp.ConnectionLimit = updatedNumberOfConnections;
```